# How to - Recover deleted VHD file itself, not files in the VHD in HyperV?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd, vhdx

I accidentally delete a VM running in HyperV together with VHD file from the disk.

Tried major recovery software, recuva,easeus,stellar etc but they can only recover the files within the VHD, not the VHD itself.

Does anyone has any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sounds like restoring from a backup will be required

Comment: The VHD might be in the Recycle Bin. Or it might be among the files listed by the recovery software (besides the other files). Otherwise, no solution.

Comment: No Backups are available, VHD not in recycle bin, not listed among the files.

Comment: I've never tested it, however, found some mentions of the following software. Might help.
https://www.data-recovery-solutions.com/vhd-recovery.php